# MySQL query GROUP BY WHERE IN

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like:

```
+------+--------+-----------+
|      | name   | type_id   |
+------+--------+-----------+
|    1 | Bob    | 3         |
|    2 | Tony   | 2         |
|    3 | Sheila | 2         |
|    4 | Sarah  | 8         |
|    5 | Tom    | 7         |
+------+--------+-----------+
```

and I want to group my type_id into a new column, called 'type' . type_id 2 and 8 would have the value 'yes', everything else 'no' so my results would look something like:

```
+------+--------+-----------+------+
|      | name   | type_id   | type |
+------+--------+-----------+------+
|    1 | Bob    | 3         | no   |
|    2 | Tony   | 2         | yes  |
|    3 | Sheila | 2         | yes  |
|    4 | Sarah  | 8         | yes  |
|    5 | Tom    | 7         | no   |
+------+--------+-----------+------+
```

Is this even possible, if so whats it called, as I've searched the docs on 'GROUP BY' and 'JOINS' , but couldn't see a solution like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do that with a [case](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html):

```
SELECT *,CASE WHEN type_id IN (2,8) THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END as `type`
FROM yourTable
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b5a08/1)</kbd>

Comment: I was just about to post my answer! until i wrote mine u posted this +1

Comment: @Kiksy. It's the best thing ever .:).

Comment: just as another question, does this style of query have a name?

Comment: Not sure if it has a specific name. And if it has, i don't know it. sorry.